# How to use a variable as a value for attribute and setAttribute properties?

Tags: xml, dom, properties

I'm trying to use setAttribute to change the link in an iframe.

I want to get the link to change every few minutes to a new website chosen from an array.

Everything seems to work except for one thing; I can't figure out how to get setAttribute to accept a variable or array as a link. For an example, my code looks something like this:

```
var linkList = [ 'link1',
                 'link2',
                 'link3'];
function changePage() {
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
document.getElementById('iframe').src = linkList[i];
}}
var timeoutNow = setTimeout("changePage()", 3000)
```

The linkList[i] part is the part I'm having trouble with - how do I get the src attribute to be set to a link stored in a variable or array?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The line that starts with document. is  fine.  Use  a static variable to remember which one you're on.  like this:

```
var i = 0;
function changePage() {
    i = (i + 1) % 3;
    document.getElementById('iframe').src = linkList[i];
}
```